# How do I add a repository with Ansible on CentOS 8?

Tags: ansible, repository, centos8, ansible-module

In CentOS 7, Ansible has the `yum-repository` module that can be used for adding repositories.

In CentOS 8 there exists the `dnf` module for package management, but there doesn't seem to be a `dnf-repository` module to add repositories.

How do you achieve this on CentOS 8 with Ansible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you found out, there is not (yet ?...) a <strike>`dnf_repository`</strike> module. Meanwhile, from the [Fedora system administration guide - Managing dnf repositories](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Managing_DNF_Repositories.html)

> To define a new repository, you can either add a `[repository]` section to the `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` file, **or to a `.repo` file in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory**.

Since the [`yum_repositories` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html) manages files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` by default, it should work out of the box.

An other track to follow eventually, as stated in the [`yum_repository` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html) is to use the [`ini_file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html#ini-file-module) directly to create or modify your repository definition.